# Match Phrases (in array) in text string

Tags: php, regex, twitter

I'm using the Twitter API streaming to collect thousand of tweets every minute.
They need to be matched to a list of keywords (can contain spaces).

This is my current method:

```
$text = preg_replace( '/[^a-z0-9]+/i', ' ', strtolower( $data['text'] ) );
$breakout = explode( " ", $text );

$result = array_intersect( $this->_currentTracks, $breakout );
```

I chop the tweet into words, and the matches them against my current keywords.
This works well for all the keywords without a space ofc.

If I wanted to find for example "Den Haag", It won't show up, because the string is exploded into words (based on the spaces).

Any ideas about how I can do this in a quick way?

Kind regards,
Tim

Comment: tried using `strpos()` ?

Comment: Easiest is to just do another regex in the original string.  Thousands per minute is a pretty slow rate.  You'll be fine.

Comment: Is there a way to preform a reggex based on the array?

Comment: Yes, why not use a regex for matching `key|words|like|Den Haag`? Easy to construct from an array list.

Comment: @mario don't forget the word boundary markers

Comment: I'm really bad in Reggex, any example ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a smallish set of keywords to search for, you might be happy with the basic regexp approach:

```
if (preg_match('/\b(keyword1|keyword2|Den Haag)\b/i', $data['text'], $matches) !== FALSE) {
}
```

With a large set of keywords that might be a bit suboptimal, though, especially if the keywords tend to start with the same prefix ('keyword' in the example here). On the other hand, it might well be faster than some more complex PHP implementations of a search algorithm.

You can prepare the regexp string from your keywords array with implode('|', $array), however, if you're getting the keywords from an external source (it's not hardcoded in the script) you'll have to make sure it's escaped properly (keywords could contain characters like |).